# adding padding to the stylesheet of a QPushbutton disable animation

Tags: qt

When I add padding in a QPushButton's stylesheet the animation doesnt occur during button press,release:

```
QPushButton{
     border: 1px solid green;
     padding: 2px;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
```

By that, I mean the button text does not sink in.

Is this normal?

Comment: What animation are you expecting?

Comment: if I press the button I do not see its text sink in.

Comment: There is also the border that is not changing but I can deal with that for now because this seems to happen with any style I apply to it and is not relevant to the addition of padding (ie I probably didnt include it in the style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to add padding and see the text sink in.  The only way I could see it possible and I havent tried it would be to translate the text to the right and to the bottom on the pressed sub-control but that remains to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define at least the `pressed` pseudo state. For instance :

```
QPushButton{ border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 4px; }
QPushButton:pressed{ border: 2px solid green; padding-left : 2px;
                     padding-top : 2px;border-radius: 4px; }
```

See Qt documentation : [Customizing QPushButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton)

Comment: I edited my answer to solve the padding problem. It is strange if it doesn't work for you. On which platform and with which Qt version are you working ?
I'm able to make it work on Mac Leopard and WinXP, with Qt 4.6.1.
How are you setting the stylesheet on your button ? Are you using Designer ?